# Can multiple EC2 Auto Scaling Group policies be defined for a single environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

Given an Auto Scaling Group with a single EC2 environment, am I able to create a scheduled scaling policy and a CPU target tracking policy for the ASG?

For example, I would like to define a scheduled scaling policy to scale up at 10am and scale down at 4pm. In combination with the scheduled policy, I would like to also have a CPU target tracking policy to handle any unexpected load the scheduled scaling does not account for.

Sorry if this question had been asked already as I was not able to find it if it was :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to mix up dynamic scaling with schedules actions. Through the console you go the "Automatic scaling" section in your ASG and add each autoscaling rule you mentioned. Notice that for the scheduled action you must specify a min-max-desired which you can set to a fixed number.